# running 64-bit Linux in Virtual box 5.0.0 on windows 7

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, 64-bit

Hi i am very new to virtual machines. I have Virtual box 5.0.0 running on windows 7 64-bit. I have installed extension packs, however when i go to set up Kali Linux 64-bit, it doesn't give me a option of a 64-bit Linux version at the start of setup and thus the virtual machine will not work. Could anyone please help as i am really stuck, have looked through other forums/posts/etc but cannot find anything that directly applies to this problem and as I am new to this all i really don't know where to go from this point. Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox doesn't have an exhaustive Linux distribution list, but can choose a generic version like `Other Linux (64-bit)`, or another one with specific kernel version matching your installation.

[image: Other Linux (64-bit)]

Also, in order to virtualize a 64-bit OS you have to enable your VT-x or AMD-v features in your BIOS.

[image: Enable VT-x BIOS]

Comment: the problem is that in the drop down list it only has 32-bit versions of everything, nothing with any 64-bit format at all. Is there anywhere you know that maybe has a different virtual box that will have 64-bit or are they all the same for windows 7 etc? Thank you for replying to my query.

Comment: oh sorry did not see the part about BIOS setup will give that a shot, i feel ahamed to say but will probably find that difficult has i have done very little relating to BIOS setup. But thanks for the pointers i'm sure i will find my way through it, thanks.

Comment: First, check if your CPU have this functionnality, if you have an intel CPU you can look at http://ark.intel.com/.
Or at http://products.amd.com/ for AMD Processors.

For Intel Core i7 4900MQ Processor, there is the line  "**Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x)**" set to **yes**

Comment: Hi gain have run into problems. In the BIOS mode on my laptop those sort of options appear absolutely nowhere. It is an Intel Celeron 900. In the BIOS the there are 5 categories. Main, advanced, security, boot and exit. But nowhere are any of these are any VT-x options. I dont know if the BIOS version may make a difference but it is 'Phoenix 1.10'. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU doesn't seem to have Hardware virtualization functionnality.

http://ark.intel.com/m/products/41498/Intel-Celeron-Processor-900-1M-Cache-2_20-GHz-800-MHz-FSB#@product/specifications

VirtualBox cannot run 64-bits guest OSes without VT instructions. But this limitation is not present in QEMU or VMWare Player. You can try those softwares.

Comment: Thank you very much I think I will just try the alternative software, as this seems like is going nowhere. I think you must be right just doesn't seem to be possible using virtual box on this laptop. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: However which version of VMWare Player would you consider the best (or easiest) for running Kali, etc?